# How to replace a "for loop" to make it run faster

Tags: matlab

I have a for loop as a part of my code. Its run takes too long, specially for large lenghts of `I`. Is there any way to make it faster?

```
    [temp,I,J] = unique(cc_new,'rows');
    I=sort(I);
    cc_new = cc_new(I,:);
    C = C(I,:);

    n = 0;
    clear K;

    for i = 1 : length(I)-1,
        for j = i+1 : length(I),
            if sum(intersect(cc_new(i,:),cc_new(j,:)))-sum(cc_new(j,:))==0,
                n = n+1;
                K(n) = j;
            end
        end
    end

    if n > 0,
        K=unique(K);
        removed = cc_new(K',:);
        [temp,I]=setdiff(cc_new,removed,'rows');
        I=sort(I);
        cc_new = cc_new(I,:);
        C = C(I,:);
    end

    cc = cc_new;
```

Comment: I is a vector. I have added some detailes in the code. The for loop is repeated several times in my code. So, its run time is more important.

Comment: @Meher81: Could you describe what the code does? Is it simply counting the number of rows which have pairwise the same elements?

Comment: Does `cc_new` have negative numbers, floating point numbers, zeros?

Comment: For cc_new=[1,1,2;2,1,1] the code returns n=0, so it does not pairwise compare the rows for equal elements. I fail to understand what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: It is a matrix contains positive integers and zeros.

Comment: The code checks `cc` for redundancy and removes redundant elements from `C`.

Comment: @Meher81: Redundant elements are those which contain the same set of numbers? So `cc_new=[1,1,2;2,1,1]` should be changed to `cc_new=[1,1,2]` (what the code currently does not detect as redundant)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    index0=find (A (:,2 )==0);
    A0=A(index0,:);
    A1=A;
    A1(index0,:) =[]; % A ( : , 2 ) ~= 0
    [ia1,ja1]=size(A1);
    A20 = A1;
    A30 = A20 ( : , 1 );
    A40 = A0 ( : , 1 );
    A50 = [ A30 ; A40 ];
    [~,ix2,~] = unique(A50,'rows');
    A60 = A0;
    ix3 = ix2-ia1;
    A60(ix3,:) = [];
    A21 = A1;
    A31 = A21 ( : , 2 );
    A41 = A0 ( : , 1 );
    A51 = [ A31 ; A41 ];

[~,ix21,~] = unique(A51,'rows');
A61 = A0;
ix31 = ix21-ia1;
A61(ix31,:) = [];
AN = [ A1 ; A60 ; A61 ];
```